# PowerBI: Data table relationship to multiple facts table

Tags: database-design, powerbi, data-modeling, powerbi-desktop

I have a multiple star schema or a [galaxy schema](https://www.guru99.com/star-snowflake-data-warehousing.html#5). What I mean is, there are multiple dimension tables and multiple fact tables with different granularity, all arranged or related like a galaxy schema- I have made sure none have circular relation, all have many-many relationship (because I was getting blank in slicer) and both direction (so that I can slice and dice in any way).

Now, I have to introduce a 'Date' table which includes: Month, Year, Type (that classifies, whether the date is history or forecast). I am only able to have relation to any one of 4 fact tables. Unable to have another relationship as it become circular and relationship gets inactive. How can I introduce this shared dimension to all the fact tables?

Attached is the model:
[image]

To summarize, all the dimensions table are hierarchy of products, and suppliers. The facts tables are at different granularity.

When I create a table with 'Type, Date, Lower Product IDs, Facts' - I get the required results
But, while creating a table with 'Type, Date, SKU IDs, Supplier IDs, Facts' - I get duplicate Dates and Type (i.e. history Jan 2021 and forecast Jan 2021)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I introduce this shared dimension to all the fact tables?

Don't enable bi-directional cross filtering on the relationship between the dimension and the fact, and then the dimension can flow filters to multiple fact tables.

And consider scoping your Power BI Data Set to just one or two fact tables at-a-time.  Having a big schema with lots of fact tables can get complicated and confusing for users.

Comment: What I did is linked 'data month yr type' to 'data sku id supplier id' with single direction from dimension. This results in incorrect aggregation of facts and shows all suppliers that are not present in 'data sku id supplire id'